# i have string 'Tprintthisstring' and want output into 'T,pri,ntt,his,str,ing' . can someone help me on this

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to print in Oracle.

```
Input string : 'Tprintthisstring' 

Output string: 'T,pri,ntt,his,str,ing'
```

Comment: according to which rules? Always 1 then 3? using the case as in a current answer? What about string AZERthing with more than one (and 3) upper case letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set serveroutput ON; 
DECLARE 
    l        VARCHAR2 (256); 
    l1       VARCHAR2 (256); 
    len      NUMBER; 
    str1     VARCHAR (20); 
    str2     VARCHAR (20); 
    a        NUMBER (10); 
    counter  NUMBER (10); 
    i        NUMBER (10); 
    p_string VARCHAR2(1000) := 'aaasasdasd,rrt'; 
    decml    NUMBER (10) := 3; 
BEGIN 
    a := 1;

```
i := 1; 

l := Substr (p_string, Instr (p_string, ',') + 1); 

l1 := Substr (p_string, 0, Instr (p_string, ',') - 1); 

len := Length (l1); 

IF len <= decml THEN 
  str1 := l1 
          ||',' 
          ||l; 
ELSE 
  counter := Floor (len / decml); 

  FOR a IN REVERSE i .. counter LOOP 
      str1 := str1 
              || '.' 
              || Substr (l1, -decml * a, decml); 
  END LOOP; 

  IF ( counter * decml = len ) THEN 
    str1 := Substr (str1, 2, Length (str1)) 
            || ',' 
            || l; 
  ELSE 
    str2 := Substr (l1, 1, ( len - ( counter * decml ) )); 

    str1 := str2 
            || str1 
            || ',' 
            || l; 
  END IF; 
END IF; 

dbms_output.Put_line(str1);
```

END;

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to prepend a comma before every block of 3 lower-case letters.

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( 'Tprintthisstring', '([a-z]{3})', ',\1' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE('TPRINTTHISSTRING','([A-Z]{3})',',\1') |
> | :---------------------------------------------------- |
> | T,pri,ntt,his,str,ing                                 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4b3cc4c3ff513f722ea2b9ecca8f9ba)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, this returns the result you want, but I have no idea whether it'll work *always* as you didn't explain rules that lead from source to target.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Tprintthisstring' from dual
  3    ),
  4  temp as
  5    -- c1 is the first letter
  6    -- then split the rest into groups of 3 letters (rows)
  7    (select substr(substr(col, 2), 3 * (level - 1) + 1, 3) c2,
  8            level lvl,
  9            substr(col, 1, 1) c1
 10     from test
 11     connect by level <= length(substr(col, 2))
 12    )
 13  -- aggregate the c2 string back, separated by comma
 14  select c1 ||','||
 15        listagg(c2, ',') within group (order by lvl) result
 16  from temp
 17  where c2 is not null
 18  group by c1;

RESULT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T,pri,ntt,his,str,ing

SQL>
```

I'm not sure why you tagged it as PL/SQL and what kind of PL/SQL should it be; an anonymous block? Stored procedure? Whatever it is, the above query can easily be converted to PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks.. foe this code.but my input string length is not fixed and comma place is dynamic input by user

Comment: You're welcome. Code I wrote just returns result you wanted. As I wrote in my answer: you have to explain the rules, otherwise it won't work.